# Tap:i18n doesn't work with angular-meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, internationalization, meteor-helper, angular-meteor

I'm working with angular-meteor and i need a internazionalization package.

I found the [Tap:i18n](https://atmospherejs.com/tap/i18n) package and i think is the most complete pkg for now.

The problem is that the helper that tap:i18n use is incompatible with angular.

```
{{ _ "hello" }}
```

return an error from angular:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '"hello"' is an unexpected token at column 3 of the expression [_ "hello"] starting at ["hello"].
```

I think that the solution is to change the helper "_" with an angular filter e.g.:

```
{{ "hello" | tapI18n }}
```

but i don't know how do this.

I wrote into 2 existing issues on github but the persons that opened theese haven't get answer.

https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n/issues/96

https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n/issues/118

any ideas?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

[tap:i18n](https://atmospherejs.com/tap/i18n) is for **"blaze-meteor"** project, so I think maybe you need change your direction.

If you have an **angular-meteor** project, you can use [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate), on atmosphere, there is an package called [planettraining:angular-translate](https://atmospherejs.com/planettraining/angular-translate), you can have a try.

If you have an **angular2-meteor** project, you can use [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate). But for this one, right now there is no package on atmosphere, so you need repackage it by yourself. Or wait until meteor 1.3 comes out, then you can use this NPM package directly.